# Application master is killed by yarn while running spark job in cluster mode randomly

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, cloudera, oozie

The error log is as follows :

```
20/05/10 18:40:47 ERROR yarn.Client: Application diagnostics message: Application application_1588683044535_1067 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1588683044535_1067_000002 exited with  exitCode: -104
Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: [2020-05-10 18:40:47.661]Container [pid=209264,containerID=container_e142_1588683044535_1067_02_000001] is running 3313664B beyond the 'PHYSICAL' memory limit. Current usage: 1.5 GB of 1.5 GB physical memory used; 3.6 GB of 3.1 GB virtual memory used. Killing container.
Dump of the process-tree for container_e142_1588683044535_1067_02_000001 :
    |- PID PPID PGRPID SESSID CMD_NAME USER_MODE_TIME(MILLIS) SYSTEM_TIME(MILLIS) VMEM_USAGE(BYTES) RSSMEM_USAGE(PAGES) FULL_CMD_LINE
    |- 209264 209262 209264 209264 (bash) 0 0 22626304 372 /bin/bash -c LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/cdhparcels/CDH-6.1.1-1.cdh6.1.1.p0.875250/lib/hadoop/../../../CDH-6.1.1-1.cdh6.1.1.p0.875250/lib/hadoop/lib/native:" /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_181-cloudera/bin/java -server -Xmx1024m -Djava.io.tmpdir=/hdfs4/yarn/nm/usercache/aiuat/appcache/application_1588683044535_1067/container_e142_1588683044535_1067_02_000001/tmp -Dspark.yarn.app.container.log.dir=/hdfs16/yarn/container-logs/application_1588683044535_1067/container_e142_1588683044535_1067_02_000001 org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster --class 'com.airtel.spark.execution.driver.SparkDriver' --jar hdfs:///user/aiuat/lib/platform/di-platform-main-1.0.jar --arg 'hdfs://nameservice1/user/aiuat/conf/FMS/irrule/irsparkbatchjobconf.json,hdfs://nameservice1/user/aiuat/conf/FMS/irrule/irruleexecution.json' --properties-file /hdfs4/yarn/nm/usercache/aiuat/appcache/application_1588683044535_1067/container_e142_1588683044535_1067_02_000001/__spark_conf__/__spark_conf__.properties 1> /hdfs16/yarn/container-logs/application_1588683044535_1067/container_e142_1588683044535_1067_02_000001/stdout 2> /hdfs16/yarn/container-logs/application_1588683044535_1067/container_e142_1588683044535_1067_02_000001/stderr
    |- 209280 209264 209264 209264 (java) 34135 2437 3845763072 393653 /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_181-cloudera/bin/java -server -Xmx1024m -Djava.io.tmpdir=/hdfs4/yarn/nm/usercache/aiuat/appcache/application_1588683044535_1067/container_e142_1588683044535_1067_02_000001/tmp -Dspark.yarn.app.container.log.dir=/hdfs16/yarn/container-logs/application_1588683044535_1067/container_e142_1588683044535_1067_02_000001 org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster --class com.airtel.spark.execution.driver.SparkDriver --jar hdfs:///user/aiuat/lib/platform/di-platform-main-1.0.jar --arg hdfs://nameservice1/user/aiuat/conf/FMS/irrule/irsparkbatchjobconf.json,hdfs://nameservice1/user/aiuat/conf/FMS/irrule/irruleexecution.json --properties-file /hdfs4/yarn/nm/usercache/aiuat/appcache/application_1588683044535_1067/container_e142_1588683044535_1067_02_000001/__spark_conf__/__spark_conf__.properties
```

Some of the observations are :

1. Application master is getting killed. The memory error is in container of application master itself, not of executer containers.
2. This job is scheduled via oozie and some instances of job get succeeded and some fails randomly without any pattern. The amount of input data is same in every case.
3. I have tried the most of solutions suggested on internet. 
    yarn.mapareduce.map.mb  and yarn.mapareduce.reduce.mb is set to 8gb already.
4. I have also tried increasing driver memory , executer memory , overhead memory of both to very high value, low value, tweaking with these configurations but some instances still failed in every case.
5. yarn.nodemanager.vmem-pmem-ratio is set to 2.1 vnem check is disable and pnem check is enabled. Unfortunately these configurations can't be changed as it's a production cluster.
6. yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb is set to 5GB already. yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb is set to 26GB

Some of my other confusions are :

1. Why is memory available to Application master container only 1.5GB as shown in logs if yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb is set to 5GB ?
2. As this error comes in the container of application master itself and as per my understanding , application master and spark driver runs in the same jvm. I am concluding that that this error is because of either spark driver memory or application master memory not being sufficient. Does my conclusion seem correct ?

Comment: _"as per my understanding , application master and spark driver runs in the same jvm"_ >> it depends. In `yarn-client` mode, the driver runs inside the Oozie launcher container, then it spaws a YARN job with 1 AppMaster (mostly idle) and N executors. Problem is the Oozie laucher memory size is not set by Spark driver size property hence you may run into an OOM if you don't manually sync the Oozie action prop with the Spark prop.

Comment: In `yarn-cluster` mode, the oozie launcher container only runs a JVM for the "Spark client" that spawns a YARN job with 1 container for Appmaster-with-embedded-driver (sized defined by Spark driver size +overhead +offheap although it depends on the version, duh) and N containers for executors (as requested by the driver).

Comment: Note that in Oozie 4.x the properties for the launcher container -- incl. memory size -- are defined as `oozie.launcher.x.y.z` (not sure about Oozie 5.x since the launcher is merged with its own AppMaster)

Comment: IMHO the 1.5GB value matches either `yarn-cluster ` a driver size of 1GB + 384MB for overhead, rounded upwards to the next size increment that YARN allows (visibly 512MB in your case), or `yarn-client` with a default container size of 1.5MB for the Oozie launcher

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this error. So, I thought I will answer this here.

In case of cluster mode, driver memory configurations can't be given on runtime after a sparksession is already created as application master was already launched and driver runs inside yarn application master container. What I was trying to do is to pass driver memory conf via "spark.driver.memory" after creating a sparksession. Spark doesn't give any error for this case and even shows the driver memory as exactly what was provided via this conf in the environment tab on spark ui page, which makes identifying the issue even more difficult. Application master memory was taken as default value 1GB instead of the memory I provided and thus, I was getting this error.

Comment: _"What I was trying to do is to pass driver memory conf via "spark.driver.memory" after creating a sparksession."_ >> that's the kind of information that was missing in your post. As you said yourself, this is an absurd thing to do when you understand that the Spark session, driver-side,runs inside a JVM that is _already created with fixed memory limits_...